# How can a value be stored so that it's shared across an entire request in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can a value be stored so that it's shared across an entire request (i.e. make it accessible in controllers , views and models )?

1. Put is as a Global variable
2. Create a Singleton and store it in a class variable
3. Store it in a thread locally.

Comment: Global variable should work (by definition, hehe). Although it's not the route I'd take.

Comment: What is your use case? Does the variable change on each request?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what is your preferred route then?

Comment: @scaryguy: depends on a concrete scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any instance variable initialized in a `controller#action` will be available in the views. To use these variables in a model, you could pass them as an argument to the model method.

Comment: I am asking within the given choices. its an objective type question.

Comment: If this is really for one request, do it this way. If it is more "session" related, then do something like @xlembouras solution below for caching/persistence. Please do not attempt to persist variables across requests as it will lead to pain and suffering.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can store value in session like this `session[:foo] = @foo`, and you should have ability to get this value whatever you want

Comment: `session` is not available in models

Answer (score 1):

Variable set at start-up and for which the value is not supposed to change. Shared and identical for all users and all threads: use a constant.

Variable set at run-time for which the value can change. Shared and identical for all users and all threads: use class instance variable.

Variable 'private' for a user and a thread, but accessible across all rails components: use a Thread variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom configuration variable in your initializers,
create a file say `global_var.rb inside your config/initializers`

inside this file declare any variable and assign it a value like

custom_var = "Hello World!"

now to use this you have to do

Rails.configuration.custom_var = custom_var , so your global_var.rb should include

```
custom_var = "Hello World!"
Rails.configuration.custom_var = custom_var
```

now you have `Rails.configuration.custom_var` which will output `Hello World` and you can use it anywhere.

but this will be initialized whenever you start your application/rails server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to have this functionality, is to have a session (or session like) store mechanism.

Having a session store will make your data available in all controllers and views, and you can pass the data as a parameter to your models.

If you don't want to have that kind of data in your session, you can store a hashed uid in the session and make a look up in an additional store (such as redis). eg:

```
uid = session[:uid]
data_1 = Redis.handler_get_data_1_by_id(uid)
```

which will give you:

- flexibility (you can add extra data to a user or whatever you identifier is)
- security (your data are on your system only and by having a hashed_id different sessions can't access each others data)
- performance (as redis' performance is similar to a memcache)